# Stored procedure error in vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, vb.net-2010

this is my function:

```
     Public Function getLocation(ByVal res As String, ByVal tblName As String) As DataTable
    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("jk_getLocation", cn)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", res)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableName", tblName)

    If resDT.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        resDT.Rows.Clear()
    End If
    resDS.Clear()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    Try
        da.Fill(resDS, "nb")
        resDT = resDS.Tables(0)
    Catch exe As SqlException
        logFile("SP getLocation ----" + exe.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        logFile("SP getLocation ----" + ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return resDT
End Function
```

that's how i'm calling it:

```
resDT = nb.getLocation(res.ToString(), code)
```

that's my stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[jk_getLocation]
@id varchar(100),
@TableName varchar(100)
as
begin
select * from b where id=@id and name=@TableName
end
```

when i execute my procedure from SQL it works fine and returns the correct data..
but when i run it from vb.net i keep getting `Procedure or function 'jk_getLocation' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied.` although i'm passing all the parameters

Comment: should var char(100) be varchar(100)? assuming copy and paste error.

Comment: well yeah it varchar(100)...

Comment: is your ID in your Db an int by any chance? Also are you stepping through making sure just before the procedure is proced, your @id param is getting populated

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the command type to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`

That said you may be wondering why you're getting the error

> Procedure or function 'jk_getLocation' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied

If you run SQL Profiler and execute your method as it currently is you'll see something like the following line

```
exec sp_executesql N'jk_getLocation',
            N'@id nvarchar(3),@TableName nvarchar(6)',
              @id=N'100',@TableName=N'foobar'
```

This is what SQL server executes when you use a CommandText SqlCommand with parameters (most often used with parameterized queries)

If you execute the above in SSMS you'll get the same error

You can fix this by either by adding

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

or by changing your command text to include the parameter names

```
Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("jk_getLocation @id, @tablename", cn)
```

which would be executed as

```
exec sp_executesql N'jk_getLocation @id, @tablename', //Note the parameters declared here
            N'@id nvarchar(3),@TableName nvarchar(6)',
              @id=N'100',@TableName=N'foobar'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Public Sub getLocation(resDT As DataTable, params As Hashtable)
    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand

    command.Connection = cn
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    command.CommandText = "jk_getLocation"
    command.CommandTimeout = 10

    For i = 0 To ht.Count - 1
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(params.Keys(i), params.Values(i))
    Next

    Dim adapter as New SqlDataAdapter(command)

    Try
        adapter.fill(resDT)
    Catch ex As Exception
        logFile("SP getLocation ----" + ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

To call the method:

```
Dim params As New Hashtable

params.Add("@id", res)
params.Add("@TableName", tblName)
nb.getLocation(resDT, params)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Function getLocation(ByVal res As String, ByVal tblName As String) As DataTable
    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    cn.Open()
    command.Connection = cn
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    command.CommandText = "jk_getLocation"
    command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = res
    command.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tblName

    Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter
    sda = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = New DataTable

    sda.Fill(dt)

    Return dt

End Function
```